# change to private or @nonobjc

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, appdelegate, xcode8

I am working on a tutorial that is creating an social media type app. I am using Firebase and have implemented all the things needed from there guides, all is working except this code below.

It is saying there is an error and asking to fix, but making it private or adding @nonobjc.

This is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

There is a version of code on the Firebase site but it is in Objective C:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

    BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                  openURL:url
                                                        sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                               annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];

    return handled;
}
```

Hope this helps and makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, warnings about app delegate methods needing to be changed to `private` or `@nonobjc` is an indication that an app delegate method signature is not correct. Consider:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    ...
}
```

This has been replaced with:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    ...
}
```

And, according to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol definition, as of iOS 9, the this has been marked deprecated in favor of:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    ...
}
```

This last rendition corresponds most closely to that Objective-C code sample you shared with us.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this makes sense now.